# Can I layout multiple flex items in a single flex-row column without restructuring html?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to apply the mobile-first approach to website design. Using flex for single-column layout by default. The next breakpoint should move `<aside>` to the side, but I'm struggling to keep the flow of the page.

Can I make kittens `<section>` show up below `<main>` content column instead of a new row below `<aside>` list with css flex rules? (without adding additional html elements).

Or do I need to start using a grid or some other CSS technique for this?

Current example (lime) vs expected result (pink):
[image: example]

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

main {
 max-width: 45ch;
 order: 2;
}

section {
  max-width: 45ch;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  order: 3;
}

aside {
 width: 100px;
 order: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <main>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </main>
  
  <section>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?cat">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?kat">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?kitten">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?dog">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?dogo">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?mains-cat">
  </section>
  
  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
      <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Go with `flex-direction:column` on `body`, and then specify the order of your child items with `order`.

Comment: Using flexbox seems like a bad approach to layout, I'm going to try to replace this with a grid.

Answer (score 2):

It can still be done with just a flex, but nesting is required. So, to answer to your question, unless you want start floating elements or position them absolutely, you need to change the html.

If you decide to change the html you need to create a container; aside and another container as children; in the second container you add main and section, no flex required.

I've added margins/padding/borders so you can see it better and get an idea of how it works.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

aside {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.rest-of-content-container {
  width:80%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cat-pics {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside> content </aside>
  <div class="rest-of-content-container">
    <div class="main"> Lorem ipsum </div>
    <div class="cat-pics"> Many many cat pics </div>
  </div>
</div>
```